# Parsing HTML files from Google Drive (not from a webpage) using Google Script

Tags: javascript, scripting, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am storing all of my wife's recipes in Paprika. One of the things I want to be able to do is export the entire database of recipes into a spreadsheet. Paprika only exports two formats: One is it's own proprietary *.paprika* format that is not human readable. The other is as a series of *.html* files. The HTML files contain hrecipe metadata, so I am hopeful that I can leverage that to pull out the necessary information.

I thought the best way to traverse the set of files and pull out all of the information I needed would be to put them into a Google Drive folder and use Google Sheets and Scripts to extract the necessary information.

So my question is: Is it possible to extract the necessary information from the recipe HTML files using Google Script? Google Script has an HTML parser that can look at an existing web page and pull down information from it, but I can't seem to make it work with an actual HTML file instead of a published web page.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Google Apps Script can definitely access and parse the files in a user's Drive. But that may not necessarily be easy or straightforward. Looks like the Drive Service API (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) may be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been working through the documentation and I haven't found anything yet, but I'll keep digging through it. I'm definitely a novice at this, but I have created a few working scripts before.

Answer (score 0):

How about this method? Using DriveApp, You can retrieve data from HTML file on Google Drive. I think that there are 2 patterns for retrieving data from HTML file. For this sample, a following HTML is used as a sample HTML.

#### Sample HTML :

This sample HTML is put on Google Drive.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Pattern 1 :

If XmlService can be used for your HTML file, you can use this script.

```
var fileId = "### file ID of HTML ###";
var html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Retrieve data from HTML file as string.

var data = XmlService.parse(html).getRootElement().getChild('body');
var url = data.getChild('a').getAttribute("href").getValue();
var value = data.getChild('a').getValue();
Logger.log("URL: %s, Value: %s", url, value);
```

#### Pattern 2 :

If XmlService cannot be used for your HTML file, you can retrieve data using a library "Parser". The sample script is as follows.

```
var fileId = "### file ID of HTML ###";
var html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Retrieve data from HTML file as string.

var url = Parser.data(html).from('<a href="').to('">').build();
var value = Parser.data(html).from('<a href="'+ url + '">').to('</a>').build();
Logger.log("URL: %s, Value: %s", url, value);
```

Both results are `URL: https://www.google.com/, Value: Google`.

#### References :

- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)
- [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)
- [About a library "Parser"](http://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Jody Lane Did my answer work? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved.